# Pasar datos de la hoja 1 a la hoja 2 con un botón de script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Script en Google Sheets para grabar calificaciones de una hoja a otra, la idea es tomar los datos de la hoja 1 pegarlos como valores en la hoja 2 y al mismo tiempo borrar los datos en la hoja 1, mediante un botón que ejecute el script, y así para permitir que se anoten nuevos datos en la hoja 1.

Intente grabar una macro pero dada mi inexperiencia, probablemente hay algo que hago mal porque luego la macro se ejecuta mal.

Video explicativo acá: http://nimb.ws/CQyPfd

Comment: Hola Carlos, Stack Overflow es un sitio donde resolver dudas no donde conseguir proyectos gratis, has probado ha hacer algo de código?

Comment: Desde que me suscribí lo tuve claro, no busco un proyecto grátis, sino orientación. Con el aporte del compañero tomasz intento adaptar a mi proyecto, aún sin éxito, pues no tengo experiencia programando. Espero ir ganando experiencia poco a poco y poder ser yo quien entregue aportes en la comunidad. Saludos Pako

Comment: Perfecto! El próximo día intenta poner algo de tu código y explicar donde te has quedado atascado, eso te dará muchas más respuestas. Nos vemos!

Answer (score 1):

Hola Carlos He creado este Macro y segun tu descripcion a mi me va de perla.

```
function myFunction1() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  // seleciona el rango de las celdas
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1:B4').activate(); 
  // crea una hoja nueva 
  spreadsheet.insertSheet(1);
  // copia de una hoja y pega a la otra
  spreadsheet.getRange('\'Hoja 1\'!A1:B4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  // seleciona primera hoja
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Hoja 1'), true);
  // limpia datos anteriormente selecionados y copiados
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().clear({contentsOnly: true, skipFilteredRows: true});
  spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
};
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Tomasz, no se viste el video con mi archivo, en este caso, como puedo hacer para que copia el segundo rango de la primera hoja? repito el código spreadsheet.getRange('\'Hoja 1\'!A1:B4').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false) ?

Comment: el rango en mi ejemplo es solo para probar, tu tienes que poner el rango de todos los datos que tiene que copiar,  supongo que son en una tabla.